# Вывести элемент у последнего нажатого чекбокса?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как выводить кнопку "*Применить*" только у последнего нажатого чекбокса?
т.е. не у самого нижнего (как в примере), а именно последнего нажатого.

В примере, например, уже выделены **BARS SILVER** и **BOSCH**, и при нажатии на **BLAK HORSE**, кнопка появится все равно у **BOSCH**. А должна появится у **BLAK HORSE**

- При нажатии на чекбокс все остальные кнопки должны убираться.
- кнопка "Применить" должна быть только у того чекбокса, который нажат последним (т.е. кнопка должна быть одна)
- уже выбранные чекбоксы должны оставаться выделены.

```js
(function ($)
{
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.check-list  :checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
  
   // определить последний выбранный элемент
   var lastElement = undefined;
   $(".check-list input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(index, element){
    lastElement = element;
   });
   
   if (lastElement == undefined)
    $('#button').hide(300);
   else
   {
        var buttonX = $('#checks-block').offset().left + 200;
        var buttonY = $(lastElement).next().offset().top + ($(lastElement).next().height() - 30 /*высота кнопки*/) / 2;
        
    $('#button').hide(300, function(){
     $('#button').css({left: buttonX, top: buttonY,}).show(300);
    });
   }
  });
 });

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="button" style="display: none; height: 30px; position: absolute; z-index: 2;">Применить</button>
<div id = 'checks-block' style = 'border: 1px solid black; z-index: 1;'>
  <div style="display: block;">
    <div tabindex="0" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 193px; border: 1px solid orange;">     
      <div style="width: 193px; height: 500px;">
        <div style="padding: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 180px;">
          <ul class="check-list">
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="1" checked="" value="13794">
              <label for="1">BARS SILVER</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="13647">
              <label for="2">BLAK HORSE</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="3" checked="" value="13659">
              <label for="3">BOSCH</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="13721">
              <label for="4">Brand</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="5" value="13835">
              <label for="5">CHAMPION</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо просто в `lastElement` положить текущий элемент, по которому сделали клик. Ну еще проверить его `prop('checked')` наверное, что если ему сделали uncheck, то действовать по старому алгоритму.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.check-list  :checkbox').on('change', function(e) {

      // определить последний выбранный элемент
      var lastElement = $(this);
      if ($(this).prop('checked') != true) {
        $(".check-list input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(index, element) {
          lastElement = element;
        });
      }

      if (lastElement == undefined)
        $('#button').hide(300);
      else {
        var buttonX = $('#checks-block').offset().left + 200;
        var buttonY = $(lastElement).next().offset().top + ($(lastElement).next().height() - 30 /*высота кнопки*/ ) / 2;

        $('#button').hide(300, function() {
          $('#button').css({
            left: buttonX,
            top: buttonY,
          }).show(300);
        });
      }
    });
  });

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="button" style="display: none; height: 30px; position: absolute; z-index: 2;">Применить</button>
<div id='checks-block' style='border: 1px solid black; z-index: 1;'>
  <div style="display: block;">
    <div tabindex="0" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 193px; border: 1px solid orange;">
      <div style="width: 193px; height: 500px;">
        <div style="padding: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 180px;">
          <ul class="check-list">
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="1" checked="" value="13794">
              <label for="1">BARS SILVER</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="13647">
              <label for="2">BLAK HORSE</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="3" checked="" value="13659">
              <label for="3">BOSCH</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="13721">
              <label for="4">Brand</label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="5" value="13835">
              <label for="5">CHAMPION</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```